# Removing calcium carbonate deposits without damaging tiles

Tags: tile, grout, chemicals

I live in an area with hard water, leading to calcium carbonate deposits all over my tiled bathroom. I want them gone, but I don't want to risk damaging the tiles.

[image]

The red arrow points at deposits that attach to the borders of the tiles. I've tried to use various cleaning chemicals and brushes to remove them but they're stuck like concrete.

In the grout (blue arrow) there are big chunks of deposits that are equally impossible to remove.

I've read a lot of tips involving acids, but I'm concerned that it would damage the glossiness of the tiles. What can I do to attack the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try with boiling white-vinegar, I use it to clean limestone buildup aluminium and steel pans. A commercial produt I found very effective is 'Viakal'

Comment: I have used white vinegar cold ( Basicly diluted acetic acid). I have good luck in the U.S. with a product called CLR (calcium, lime, rust remover). Viakal looks like a UK product that would do similar.

Comment: Viakal is the best product I can find here in Italy, I have no idea of what can be an american equivalent